# IF Input filename exists in Output folder, skip BUT ALSO SKIP in FOR Statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Here is an excerpt of a long ffmpeg script I have and I have it:

- Creating a text file of the video files in the current directory
- With a FOR statement searching through the text file
- Outputting to a subdir

What I want to add in is to not only not "process" go through the rest of the script if the file already exists but also not to process that ALREADY existing file. (In other words: If a copy of the file already exists in an output directory skip processing the file, but also to skip processing the duplicate file itself that was identified.)

````
dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S |findstr /R %Exclude-Final% /v /i>%TempFilePath%
Echo:   These are the folders being Excluded:           "!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!"
SET "FINALCOMMAND="
::******** DON'T EDIT-----Keeping Original Audio**************END END*************** 
    SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
        SET "FilesFound=0" & SET "FilesEncoded=0" & SET "output="
        for /F "delims=" %%I in (%TempFilePath%) do (
            ::ECHO ==!TIME!================Next File: %%I ========================
            SET "output=%drive%%%~pI%%~nxI" & SET "filename=%%~nxI" & SET /A FilesFound+=1
                SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
                IF exist "%drive%%%~pIoutput\%%~nxI" (SET "Convert_Audio1=N") ELSE IF !output2! == 1 (SET "Convert_Audio1=N") ELSE SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"

    
rem    ===============================
rem    FFProbe.exe evaluation of %%I files
rem    ===============================
rem    below still under the FOR statement above: for /F "delims=" %%I in (%TempFilePath%) do (
rem    ------------------------------------------------------------

rem     -----------------------------
IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    SET /A count=5
    IF /I "!output!" == "%%I" (
        SET "output=%~dp0output\!filename!"
rem     ECHO This is OUTPUT-DIR "%~dp0output\"
        MKDIR "%~dp0output\"
    ) ELSE (
        MKDIR "%drive%%%~pI"
    )

ENDLOCAL
......
ENDLOCAL
ENDLOCAL
ENDLOCAL

```
````

I want filtration to all occur here, before it goes through the FFProbe.exe processing to speed it up. I assume in the 1st IF statement there is something I can do, but when there are multiple files, or even just 2 + 1 sub-folder, it can not carry-over the right variable i.e.
this will skip file1, process file 2, and then try to process file3

EDIT:  Here is the Full Code. You will need to input what you want the destination drive to be (i.e. C: or D:  etc...). It will look for mkv's and mp4's that have eac3,flac,dts,pcm,aac,or ac3 to convert to aac. ( Batch Convert Videos audio from one format to another )

```
@ECHO OFF
SETlocal

SET drive="~dp0"
SET string=%CD%  

SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "drive=G:"
SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot^"
SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"
SET "Convert_TO=aac"
SET "Codec1=eac3"
SET "Codec2=flac"
SET "Codec3=dts" &SET "Codec4=pcm_s24le" &SET "Codec5=aac" &SET "Codec6=ac3"
SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
SET "KeepOrigAudio=N"
SET "OverWriteFiles=N"
SET "ExtractTime=Y"
SET "time_to_start_from=00:00:10" &SET "duration_to_capture=00:00:15"
SET "TempFilePath=C:\Windows\Temp\ffmpeg-CountingScript-AllFilesInCurrentDirlist%DT%--%HH%.%MM%.%SS%.txt"

IF !ExtractTime! == Y ( SET "FFmpgextractTime= -ss !time_to_start_from! -t !duration_to_capture!")
ECHO THIS IS JMK1
IF !OverWriteFiles! == Y (SET "OverWrite=-y ") ELSE (SET "OverWrite=-n ")
IF !Convert_Audio1! == Y (
    IF !Convert_TO! == aac ( set "Convert_TO=libfdk_aac" )
    SET "FFmpgConvertStream1=-c:a:0 !Convert_TO! -b:a:0 640k -disposition:a:0 default"
    IF !KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig! == Y (
        SET "FFmpgXtraStream=-c:a copy"
    )
    IF !KeepOrigAudio! == Y (
        SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy"
        SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
    )
) ELSE (
    SET "ConvertCodecs=1" 
    SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-c:a:0 copy"
    SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
)
SET "delm1=^\^>" /c:"^\^<"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=/c:"\^<!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!\^>"^"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=!Exclude-Final:,=%delm1%!^"

dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S |findstr /R %Exclude-Final% /v /i>%TempFilePath%
Echo:   These are the folders being Excluded:           "!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!"
SET "FINALCOMMAND="

SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "ProgramFolder=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg-v2020\bin"
SET "ProbeOptions=-v quiet -select_streams a:0 -show_entries "stream^^=codec_name" -of json"
SET "FilesFound=0" & SET "FilesEncoded=0" & SET "output="
for /F "delims=" %%I in (%TempFilePath%) do (
    SET "output=%drive%%%~pI%%~nxI" & SET folder=%drive%%%~pI & SET "filename=%%~nxI" & SET /A FilesFound+=1
    SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    IF exist "%drive%%%~pIoutput\%%~nxI" (SET "Convert_Audio1=N") ELSE IF !output2! == 1 (SET "Convert_Audio1=N") ELSE SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"
    IF "!Convert_Audio1!" == "Y" (
        SET "AudioCodec=" & SET "ConvertCodecs="
        for /F "eol={ tokens=1,2 delims=,:[ ]{} " %%B in ('""%ProgramFolder%\ffprobe.exe" %ProbeOptions% "%%I""') do (
            IF "%%~B" == "codec_name" (
                IF not defined AudioCodec (
                    SET "AudioCodec=%%~C"
                )
                IF "%%~C" == "%Codec1%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1"
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec2%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec3%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec4%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec5%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec6%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            )
        )
    )
)

IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    ECHO [91m==!TIME!================[0m!Codec1! [94min[0m- %%I [91m=========[0m
)
IF "%~dp0output\!filename!" == "%%I" (set "ConvertCodecs=0")

IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    SET /A count=5
    IF /I "!output!" == "%%I" (
        SET "output=%~dp0output\!filename!"
        SET /A count+=1
        MKDIR "%~dp0output\"
    ) ELSE (
        MKDIR "%drive%%%~pI"
    )
        SET "FINALCOMMAND=ffmpeg !OverWrite!-hide_banner%FFmpgextractTime% -loglevel quiet -hwaccel auto -stats -i "%%I" -map 0:v -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags -map 0:a? -map 0:s:0? -c:s:0 copy -c:v copy %FFmpgXtraStream% %FFmpgConvertStream1% %KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg% "!output!" "
        ECHO this is the command1: !FINALCOMMAND!
        !FINALCOMMAND!
        ECHO [91m=====[0mCOMPLETE[91m===============[0m .
        IF not %FilesEncoded% == 0 ECHO     This one was a failure. Count Encoded so far: "%FilesEncoded%"
        IF not errorlevel 1 SET /A FilesEncoded+=1
        powershell "$target = gi '!output!'; $source = gi '%%I'; 'CreationTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'LastAccessTime' | foreach { $target.$_ = $source.$_ }"    
        for /F "delims=" %%p in ("!ConvertCodecs!") do (
            ECHO THIS IS P: %%p
            ENDLOCAL
            SET /A FilesEncoded=%%p+FilesEncoded
        )

    ) ELSE ( ECHO ##NOT PROCESSING##: !TIME! - %%I  ## & ECHO [91m=====--[0mFILE ALREADY EXISTS! [91m======================[0m Next File [91m===========================[0m )
    )
)

IF %FilesFound% == 1 ( SET "PluralS=" ) else SET "PluralS=s"
ECHO [91m***************************************************************************************[0m
ECHO Re-encoded %FilesEncoded% of %FilesFound% video file%PluralS%.
ECHO [91m***************************************************************************************[0m
endlocal
endlocal
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: This script is no use to us without the information prior to the snippet you've posted. We need to be able to reproduce it, and without the code which specifically defined all of your used variables we cannot do that.

Comment: I should also specifically mention that there is no such command as `::`, that is a broken label, and should never be used as a replacement for the `Rem` command. You should be aware that labels cannot be used within a parenthesized block, and as such can easily break them. Please go through all of your code replacing those broken labels with the correct `rem`arks.

Comment: OK, I Added the 1st part of the batch at the bottom.  Will do on the rem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer (which I already had built-in).

In the the settings sections I designed, on the top of the full code, Under the 2nd SetLocal, `SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot^"` variable, I adjusted to `SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot,output^"`

This is then used to set the Exclude-Final variable:

```
SET ^"Exclude-Final=/c:"\^<!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!\^>"^"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=!Exclude-Final:,=%delm1%!^"
```

Which is then used here:

```
dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S |findstr /R %Exclude-Final% /v /i>%TempFilePath%
Echo:   These are the folders being Excluded:           "!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!"
```

So now as a summary I have it now excluding any folder/files "output*filename*" which I have setup as a possible output if files exist in the folder being processed from, which is next farther down the code, where it checks if file exists in current directory then create output*filename* instead.

```
IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    SET /A count=5
    IF /I "!output!" == "%%I" (
        SET "output=%~dp0output\!filename!"
        SET /A count+=1
        MKDIR "%~dp0output\"
        ) ELSE (
        MKDIR "%drive%%%~pI"
        )
```

Excerpt of full settings code with Comments:

```
SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
            :: @echo on
            ::#######0-OVERRIDE Root Directory but keep LOGGING the SAME #############
                SET "drive=G:"
            ::#######1-Exclude Specific Sub-Directories? #############
            SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot,output^"
            :: @rem SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot,Archive,Archive02.01,Archive2021.01.22,Video,Video2,aVideo,^!.Blu-Ray^ Final^"
            ::#######2-Convert Audio Track? #############
            SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"
rem Rev V2.6.8.5 ADD Convert 1st group to AC3 (channel5.1 + above?), then convert 2nd group to aac (2-channel for commentary??)
            SET "Convert_TO=aac"
            :: rem ac3 or aac
            ::#######3-Codecs Desired to Convert #############
                SET "Codec1=eac3"
                SET "Codec2=flac"
                SET "Codec3=dts" &SET "Codec4=pcm_s24le" &SET "Codec5=aac" &SET "Codec6=ac3"
::              rem pcm_s24le , null , vorbis
            ::#######4-Keep orig Audio Track? #############
            SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
            SET "KeepOrigAudio=N"
            SET "OverWriteFiles=N"
            ::#######4-Keep orig Audio Track? #############
            :: MODIFY
            ::  Extract Time AND what to Extract (as a sample test)
            SET "ExtractTime=Y"
                    SET "time_to_start_from=00:00:10" &SET "duration_to_capture=00:00:15"
            rem SET "time_to_start_from=00:00:10" &SET "duration_to_capture=03:00:00"
            ::
            ::
            ::
::#######END OF SETTINGS###############################################
::*********************************************************************
SET "TempFilePath=C:\Windows\Temp\ffmpeg-CountingScript-AllFilesInCurrentDirlist%DT%--%HH%.%MM%.%SS%.txt"
::#######END OF SETTINGS################################################################################################################################################################################################################
::**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
::#######END OF SETTINGS################################################################################################################################################################################################################
::******** DON'T EDIT-----Keeping Original Audio ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

IF !ExtractTime! == Y ( SET "FFmpgextractTime= -ss !time_to_start_from! -t !duration_to_capture!")
ECHO THIS IS JMK1
IF !OverWriteFiles! == Y (SET "OverWrite=-y ") ELSE (SET "OverWrite=-n ")
IF !Convert_Audio1! == Y (
    IF !Convert_TO! == aac ( set "Convert_TO=libfdk_aac" )
    SET "FFmpgConvertStream1=-c:a:0 !Convert_TO! -b:a:0 640k -disposition:a:0 default"
    IF !KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig! == Y (
        SET "FFmpgXtraStream=-c:a copy"
        )
    IF !KeepOrigAudio! == Y (
        SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy"
        SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
        )
    ) ELSE (
    SET "ConvertCodecs=1" 
        SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-c:a:0 copy"
        SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
    )
SET "delm1=^\^>" /c:"^\^<"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=/c:"\^<!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!\^>"^"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=!Exclude-Final:,=%delm1%!^"
:: ECHO This is the date and time:  %DT%--%HH%.%SS%
dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S |findstr /R %Exclude-Final% /v /i>%TempFilePath%
Echo:   These are the folders being Excluded:           "!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!"
```